# What shape(s) do you get from rotating a rectangle?

Tags: geometry

If you rotate a line along its center point by $X$ degrees where $X < 360^\circ$, it creates two opposing circular sectors. But if you rotate a rectangle along its center point, what shape(s) does this create?

Comment: Are you talking 2D or 3D? Maybe tag with [tag:plane-geometry] or [tag:3d].

Comment: Consider what happens when you rotate a line about a point not on the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotating a rectangle about its centre, you will get a shape whose boundary has six parts: two arcs of a circle centred at the centre of rotation, four straight segments.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zhogeijcsj

Comment: So I guess there's no official name, it's simply made of different shapes put together?